# Всегда ли обособляется оборот с предлогом "несмотря на"?

Tags: обособление

Нередко можно услышать жесткую регламентацию по этому вопросу: оборот с производным предлогом НЕСМОТРЯ НА не обособляется. И  мне хотелось бы спросить:  в чем заключается причина такого отношения к обороту? Структура предложений здесь вполне обычная, "несмотря на", казалось бы, не отличается от других производных предлогов. НО, возможно, у него особенное значение?

Можно также отметить, что даже самые авторитетные источники по отношению к обороту не столь категоричны, например:

а) РОЗЕНТАЛЬ: "При тесной смысловой связи со словом, после которого находится этот оборот, не обособляется и он, например: Пришел администратор, вызванный несмотря на поздний час".

Б) ЛОПАТИН:Оборот со словами "несмотря на" может не обособляться только в случае, если он стоит непосредственно после глагола: Он это сделал несмотря на запрет врачей (ср.: Несмотря на запрет врачей, он это сделал).

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ-КОММЕНТАРИЙ К ОТВЕТУ

Людмила, мы с Вами живем в разных измерениях, и орфография у нас разная. Вы любите  авторитарные жесткие правила и ссылки на них, а я считаю, что  такой подход мешает  развитию языка.  К примеру, для вас три принципа пунктуации  существуют номинально, а для меня они являются рабочим инструментом. Тем не менее,  мы могли бы совместно работать без особых конфликтов, делая наш форум полезным и интересным.

К сожалению, вы не ответили на мои вопросы.

1. Мне непонятно, чем обстоятельство уступки отличается от других обстоятельств (причины, цели, условия). (Я, кстати, действительно только собираюсь над этим подумать, у меня нет готового ответа).
2. Что касается объяснений по поводу обособления «обстоятельственных членов предложения, имеющих в своем составе производные предлоги и предложные сочетания», то логика Ваших рассуждений ускользает от меня совершенно. Превращение же оборота в нечто отличное от оборота представляется просто мистическим. Мне кажется, что Вы говорите: если оборот не обособляется, то он перестает быть оборотом и поэтому не обособляется. Возможно, мы пользуемся разной терминологией. Но вот я цитирую Лопатина: «Оборот со словами «несмотря на» может не обособляться…». Значит, он допускает термин «необособленный оборот».
3. Итак, вы утверждаете: «Обязательно обособляется только оборот с НЕСМОТРЯ НА». А я привожу два примера, где обособление отсутствует. Вот, к примеру, Розенталь: «Как правило, обособляется оборот с предложным сочетанием "несмотря на". Однако при тесной смысловой связи с господствующим словом, после которого он находится, оборот этот не обособляется: Явился дежурный администратор, вызванный несмотря на поздний час.  Он это сделал несмотря на запрет матери».  Эти примеры явно противоречат Вашему утверждению.

Comment: Обстоятельство уступки как правило (не буду говорить ВСЕГДА, чтоб не цеплялись к этому слову)можно заменить придаточным,в нём самом есть значение предикативности,а остальные в равной мере можно заменить, а можно нет.; Детям, по причине малолетства, не определили никаких должностей (Тургенев). – Так как дети были маленькими, им не определили никаких должностей.Оборот синонимичен придаточному и придаёт особый дополнительный смысл. за счёт предикативности.-Детям не определили никаких должностей по причине малолетства(Тургенев). - нет добавочной предикативности,только признак по действию.

Comment: Нет добавочной предикативности, нет обособления.Он это сделал, несмотря на запрет матери - появилась предикативность, основной смысл - он это сделал, остальное - пояснение, добавочный смысл. Любой оборот - это добавочная предикативность,это смысл термина ОБОРОТ, что я пыталась Вам сказать. Ничего мистического нет в том, что сочетание приобретает или теряет предикативность.Это научный факт.

Comment: В конце предложения обычно предложное сочетание стоит после глагола и по смыслу примыкает к сказуемому, потому теряется его самостоятельная предикативность, это просто обстоятельство - признак по действию.Это касается и сочетания  несмотря на, когда ему придают такое значение, а в остальных случаях обособляется ВСЕГДА.

Comment: А про "конфликты" - это не ко мне, просто не хочется проходить мимо высказываний,пытающихся посеять сомнение в моей грамотности и профессионализме. Этого я уже достаточно натерпелась, больше не буду.

Comment: А почему вы все время говорите о предикативности как о необходимом условии обособления: "Нет добавочной предикативности, нет обособления". Обстоятельства могут обособляться по различным причинам, с предикативностью не связанными, а именно:а) смысловое выделение;  б) информация второго плана (уточнение, пояснение,  попутное замечание); в) распространенность; г) удобная для обособления позиция.

Comment: Например:   Хозяин, из почтения и радости, ничего не ел. Всё снится мне заросшая травой, в глуши далёкой и лесистой, развалина часовни родовой. Коля Иволгин, по отъезде князя, сначала продолжал свою прежнюю жизнь. Добрый комендант, с согласия своей супруги, решил освободить Швабрина .Миша опустил голову и, не сразу, тихо ответил.

Comment: А грамотность и профессионализм здесь ни при чем, все уважают ваши знания, и я в том числе. Здесь конфликт систем и школ, и я всё пытаюсь понять его суть. Возможно, что мы по-разному понимаем соотношение устной и письменной речи. Для меня все смысловые оттенки, а также все пунктуационные знаки СЧИТЫВАЮТСЯ со структуры предложения, которое уже ПОСТРОИЛ АВТОР. А вы строите ОСОБУЮ письменную речь с собственной трактовкой смысла.

Answer (score 1):

```
Нередко можно услышать жесткую регламентацию по этому вопросу: оборот с производным предлогом НЕСМОТРЯ НА НЕ обособляется.
```

Вы хотели сказать, наоборот, ОБОСОБЛЯЕТСЯ? Это вызвано моим ответом на случай факультативного обособления оборота с предлогом "в связи"?

Да, это так, оборот действительно имеет отличия от других оборотов, потому что это обстоятельства УСТУПКИ, выраженные существительными с предлогами *несмотря на, невзирая на.* Такие обороты можно заменить на придаточные предложения уступки с союзом *хотя. На улицах, несмотря на яркое солнце, горели фонари. На улицах, хотя  было яркое солнце, горели фонари.* А вот оборот с "в связи" может иметь такое добавочное значение целого предложения, а может и не иметь и являться простым обстоятельством, а не обстоятельственным оборотом. Об этом я и говорила. И Грамота тоже:

http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_177

А если такой оборот стоит сразу после сказуемого, тесно к нему примыкает, он теряет значение оборота, потому и не выделяется. Просто кто-то это оговаривает, а кто-то нет, предполагая, что носители языка умеют отличать ОБОРОТ от простого члена предложения. Есть определение, а есть определительный оборот, т. е. обособленное определение, есть дополнение, а есть дополнительный оборот, так же и обстоятельство и обстоятельственный оборот. Так что

```
     авторитетные источники по отношению к обороту не столь категоричны,
```

потому что они указывают и случаи, когда оборот теряет значение оборота. Думаю, Вы это и без меня знаете. К чему был вопрос, не понимаю.

Comment: Не вижу никакого конфликта систем и школ, а я не строю ОСОБОЙ письменной речи с собственной трактовкой смысла, а пытаюсь понять, что хотел сказать автор, а вот Вы часто как раз диктуете автору, с чем я не согласна."СЧИТЫВАЮТСЯ со структуры предложения, которое уже ПОСТРОИЛ АВТОР".- это как раз мой подход, пунктуация часто факультативна , автора править не надо. Пересмотрите свои посты и увидите, как Вы пытаетесь навязать своё мнение как единственно верное.

Comment: Насчёт предикативности здесь:http://robotlibrary.com/book/28-vvedenie-v-yazykovedenie/73--62-oboroty-s-potencialnoj-predikativnostyu.html
http://rioline.narod.ru/refer/luzhin.htm   А я не ставила целью читать лекцию об обособлении, я говорила целенаправленно о названных оборотах. Кроме них, конечно, есть и уточняющие, и пояснительные,и обороты, возникшие из-за несочетаемости, и много чего другого. А в тех оборотах главное - полупредикативные отношения в дополнение к предикативным.